# Android app not building with google services (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

So I had a working version of an android app and I'm trying to add google sign in.  I followed this:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

and after the "Add the Google Services Plugin" step:

> Add the dependency to your project-level build.gradle: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha5'`
>
> Add the plugin to your
>   app-level build.gradle: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

my app fails to build with the following error:

> Failed to sync Gradle project '[my project name]' Error: Cause: failed
>   to find target with hash string 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:19' in: 
>   C:\Users\SD\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Any ideas/suggestions?  I had a friend follow the same steps and had the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you miss API 19.
I suggest you go to Tools - Android - SDK Manager or click on the SDK Manager icon and check if API 19 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I already had API 19 installed even though the error seems to indicate API19 is an issue.  I switched to API 17 and that got rid of that error but caused some new ones.

These issues are probably related to the Sherlock library that is in my app conflicting with the GooglePlayer libraries.   After switching to API 17 I resolved the other errors by removing the dependancy:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'

And adding the following:

 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
   
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'

to the project's build.gradle.